# ElasticSearch - tokenizer choose improper matching

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I would like to apply any analyser that satisfy below search. Let's take an example. Suppose I have entered below text in a document

I have store similar kind of sentence as specialization in opensearch.
Cardiologist Doctor.
Cardiac surgeon.
neuro surgeon.
cardiac specialist.
nursing care
Anatomy.
Anaesthesiology.

So, if I search `cardiac surgeon` result should be `['cardiologist', 'cardiac surgeon', 'cardiac specialist']` and it should not return `'neuro surgeon', 'nursing care'`.

Also, if I search `anatomy` result should be `['anatomoy']` and it should not return `Anaesthesiology`.

I have tried with `ngram_filter`, but when I search `cardiologist` it's returning cardiologist and `nursing care` both instead of cardiologist only.

```
"ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 15
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion using synonyms:

```
PUT synonyms
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonyms_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonyms_filter"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonyms_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "cardiac surgeon, cardiologist, cardiac surgeon, cardiac specialist"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "synonyms_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}


POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "1"}}
{ "name" : "Cardiac surgeon" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "2"}}
{ "name" : "Cardiologist Doctor" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "3"}}
{ "name" : "neuro surgeon" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "4"}}
{ "name" : "cardiac specialist" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "5"}}
{ "name" : "nursing care" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "6"}}
{ "name" : "Anatomy" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "synonyms", "_id" : "7"}}
{ "name" : "Anaesthesiology" }

GET synonyms/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "cardiac surgeon"
    }
  }
}
```

Hits:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "synonyms",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 13.066887,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Cardiac surgeon"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "synonyms",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 7.9681025,
    "_source": {
      "name": "cardiac specialist"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "synonyms",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1.567127,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Cardiologist Doctor"
    }
  }
]
```